# how to get different id in body tag?

Tags: joomla

I have placed the following code in joomla 2.5

```
<?php
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive();
  $pageclass = '';

  if (is_object($menu))
    $pageclass = $menu->params->get('pageclass_sfx');
?>

<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? htmlspecialchars($pageclass) : 'default'; ?>">
```

But it's getting `default` for all pages.

---

Ooops! its resulting this

```
<body default""="" style="font-size: 100%;">
```

Comment: the code works fine for me. I would add a `var_dump` on the menu object (`var_dump($menu);`) and you should be able to confirm that you are getting the right menu item with that param set.

Comment: I don't understand the result of var_dump http://jsfiddle.net/bFs2E/ could you analyze this

Comment: for that page, pageclass_sfx is empty, so it should print default. No idea how the code you wrote could produce anything like what you added.

Comment: I'm using beez5 template.

Comment: you should not use pageclass_sfx as is, since it could be empty (resulting in id="" which is meaningless) or could be made of two words or wrong characters. Try some functions like htmlentities or Joomla's makeAlias. And consider putting that as an extra css class instead of the id

Answer (score 0):

I take alias to make different id for each page

```
<body id="<?php echo (isset($menu) || !empty($menu))?$menu->alias:'default'; ?>">
```

And working fine.